# How do you insert a picture in LaTeX? I have tried to follow instructions online but TeXmaker won't compile my coding

Tags: graphics, errors

I'm having trouble inserting a picture into my LaTex document (using Texmaker). Does anyone know why this may be?
This is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{fig.1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It is giving me the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .1.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \includegraphics[scale=1]{fig.1}
! Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles.\clearpage ...rite \m@ne {}\vbox {}\penalty -\@Mi \end{document}
File `fig.1' not found
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX. The problem seems to be with the *.1. try renaming the file to fig1, the compiler thinks .1 is the file extension.

Comment: You can also use package `grffile`.

Comment: @Johannes_B or the package graphicx :-)

Comment: your question is unclear and could refer to one of two problems (with slightly different answers) is your actual file `fig.1.png` but graphicx isn't adding the `.png` extension, or is teh actual file `fig.1` but graphicx doesn't know it is png or eps or whatever it is?

Comment: The file was fig.1 so I suppose graphicx may not have know it was a png. I have just changed it to Figure one and it is working now.